# Store Column Name in SQL Variable to use for Dynamic drilldown report in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a report with mutiple charts in it that I made.  In each chart 5 - 6 Different category groups displayed in a 100% bar chart.  I am trying make it so the drill down report can be dynamic but I need use the category group name in my where statement to specify a pass / fail value in that specific column for each category group. This way which ever bar is clicked and which percent in the series is clicked it can be passed as a paramater value to the drill down.  I am trying to structure my sql query so the catergory group name can be passed as the column name in the where statement and series pass/fail would be passed as the value in that column like

```
Where [Policy Request] = 'Fail'
```

I'm trying to do this so I don't have to create 5 drill down reports for each chart.
Both the column I would be specifying and the value in that is once created through a case statement off other values in the query.  I have a dataset built that works every time if I set my variables to one of the column names and values that are derived from the table itself, but when I try to declare the variables with the column and value I generated from a case statement I get this message every time

```
Invalid column name 'Fail'.
```

Even though Fail is actually the value I'm looking for not the column.  I didn't change the structure of the where statement at all from when I tested it so I'm not sure why its doing that. Also if don't use the variable for the value and just specify it in the query but keep the Column name as a variable it works.  Please I'm still a newbie, if there is something I'm missing here or a better way of doing this I'm all ears.  Here is my query.

```
DECLARE @MyParm varchar(256) = '[Policy Request]'
DECLARE @Resource varchar(256) = 'Fail'
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 

'SELECT 
* 
FROM (
SELECT 
summ.ResourceID,
sy.name0,
sy.User_Name0,
Case 
    when Substring(sy.Operating_System_Name_and0,11,7) + '' '' + RTRIM(Substring(sy.Operating_System_Name_and0,34,2)) = ''Windows 10'' Then ''Windows 10''
    when Substring(sy.Operating_System_Name_and0,11,7) + '' '' + RTRIM(Substring(sy.Operating_System_Name_and0,34,3)) = ''Windows 6.1'' Then ''Windows 7''
    Else ''Unknown''
End as ''OS'',
case 
    when summ.LastEvaluationHealthy = 1 then ''Pass''
    when summ.LastEvaluationHealthy = 2 then ''Fail''
    when summ.LastEvaluationHealthy = 3 then ''Unknown''
end as ''Last Evaluation Healthy'',
Case 
    When summ.IsActiveDDR = 1 Then ''Pass''
    When Summ.IsActiveDDR = 0 Then ''Fail''
End as ''Discovery Request'', 
summ.LastDDR,
case 
    when summ.IsActiveHW = 0 then ''Fail''
    when summ.IsActiveHW = 1 then ''Pass''
end as ''Hardware Inventory'',
summ.LastHW,
case 
    when summ.IsActiveSW = 0 then ''Fail''
    when summ.IsActiveSW = 1 then ''Pass''
end as ''Software Inventory'',
summ.LastSW,
case 
    when summ.ISActivePolicyRequest = 0 then ''Fail''
    when summ.ISActivePolicyRequest = 1 then ''Pass''
end as ''Policy Request'',
summ.LastPolicyRequest,
summ.ExpectedNextPolicyRequest,
case 
    when summ.IsActiveStatusMessages = 0 then ''Fail''
    when summ.IsActiveStatusMessages = 1 then ''Pass''
end as ''Status Messages'',
summ.LastStatusMessage ,
case summ.LastEvaluationHealthy 
    when 1 then ''Pass'' else ''Fail'' 
end as ''Client Health Evaluation'',
summ.LastHealthEvaluation,
summ.ClientRemediationSuccess,
case 
    when summ.ClientRemediationSuccess = 1 then ''Pass''
    when summ.ClientRemediationSuccess = 2 then ''Fail''
    else ''''
end as ''ClientRemediationSuccessDescription''

FROM v_CH_ClientSummary summ
Left join v_R_System sy on summ.ResourceID = sy.ResourceID
where 
(sy.Operating_System_Name_and0 like ''Microsoft Windows NT Workstation%'' or sy.Operating_System_Name_and0 is null)
)a

Where ('+@MyParm+') = ('+@Resource+')'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You really, really should not do dynamic SQL this way, it is open to injection and generally incorrect results.

The best way to do this is to use **`QUOTENAME`** for column names. This means that you **do not** add the brackets `[]` in the client. And you should store them in `nvarchar(128)` (an easy to remember alias is `sysname`).

**Pass through parameters properly** using `sp_executesql`. Notice how `@Resource` is actually part of the dynamic SQL code, not concatenated onto it.

Also, use `nvarchar(max)` (Unicode) for SQL code:

```sql
DECLARE @MyParm sysname = 'Policy Request'
DECLARE @Resource varchar(256) = 'Fail'
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL = 

N'SELECT 
* 
FROM
................
................
Where (' + QUOTENAME(@MyParm)+ N') = (@Resource);'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Resource varchar(256)', @Resource = @Resource;
```

Comment: Okay cool, that worked.  So its the QUOTENAME that prevents injection somehow or calling the sp?  I saw examples of this but wasn't sure what it did so i left it out.  Ill look up more on both

Comment: Both. You need to use `QUOTENAME` for columns because you cannot supply a column name in a parameter, you have to embed it, but you need the quoting because it may have spaces, brackets or other invalid info. But actual data can be passed through in regular parameters with `sp_executesql`

Comment: Agreed that this is the way to do it, that's why my answer said "To fix your query 'as-is' " but it was 2am so I didn't expand on that!

Answer (score 1):

To fix your query as-is you just need to double the quotes around the @Resource parameter

```
WHERE (' + @MyParm + ') = (''' + @Resource + ''')'
```

your original version would end up looking like this

```
WHERE ([Policy Request]) = (Fail)
```

instead of

```
WHERE ([Policy Request]) = ('Fail')
```

> **Note:** You don't need the parentheses so you could shorten it to output
> `WHERE [Policy Request] = 'Fail'`

Comment: Thanks,  When i printed it id did look like that so makes sense.  What i couldn't understand and is why it worked when i specified a different column  and value.